# how do I init a base constructor within curly braces of derived constructor? c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to initialize a base-class member item through a derived class. The problem I have is that the value I'm passing is dependant of "x".
so here's what I'm doing:

```
Derived:: Derived()
{
    uint8 number = getNumber();
    P p;

    if (number == 3)
    {
         p = P1;
    }
    else
    {
    p = P2;
    }

    Base(p);
}
```

I get the error "no default constructor exists for class "Base". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you define the constructor Base::Base (P p) in the base class?

Comment: @HJuls2 - It is defined. There's no `Base()` however, as the error indicate. `Base(p);` is not a c'tor call. It defines an object named `p` of type `Base`, attempting to default construct it.

Comment: Base(p) is the constructor call. Base::Base(P p);

Comment: It's not a c'tor call. It may look like one, but it isn't how it's parsed

Comment: well that's part of the error... :)

Comment: It's part of the error because declaring an object always requires it to be constructed. `p` is a object declaration, believe it or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can only initialize a base class in the member initializer list sequence of a constructor. If that requires calling some other code, you can delegate that to a helper function:

```
P calculate_p() {
  uint8 number = getNumber();
  if (number == 3)
    return P1;

  return P2; 
}

Derived::Derived() : Base(calculate_p())
{
}
```

Comment: and calculate_p isn't part of the class D?

Comment: @NoaRegev - Your code sample didn't indicate it has to be. It's usually best to go with the loosest coupling possible. If `calculate_p` doesn't require access to the class, better make it a hidden utility free function.

Comment: @NoaRegev - Glad to hear it :)